# What Does the Beta Means in Quantile Regression?

Tags: regression, quantiles

I am trying to work out this formula here. However I am unsure what does the Beta stands for. Hope I get some help here. Thank you. [image]

This is part of the IMF Global Financial Stability Report October 2017. In page 133. Thanks alot!!

Comment: The $\beta$s are the regression coefficients. The process to interpret the coefficients is similar to what we do with other types of regression. [About interpretation of the results of quantile regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19243/about-interpretation-of-the-results-of-quantile-regression)

Comment: I see. Thank you.